# javascript array error: array[n] is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

relevant code:

```
function stepNetwork() {
    for(i = 0; i<maxNeurons; i++) {
        if(neuronArray[i].charge >= neuronArray[i].threshhold) {
            var elapsed = ((new Date()).getTime()) - neuronArray[i].lastFired;
            if(elapsed >= 5000){
                fireNeuron(i);
            }
        }
    }
}

function fireNeuron(n){
    //get number of outputs on this neuron
    var outs = neuronArray[n].outputs.length;
    for(p = 0; p < outs; p++) {
        sendChargeTo = neuronArray[n].outputs[p];
        addCharge(sendChargeTo);
    }
    neuronArray.charge = 0;
    neuronArray.lastFired = ((new Date()).getTime());
}

function addCharge(n) {
    neuronArray[n].charge++;//HERES THE ERROR!!
}
```

Here is what firebug is telling me:

```
neuronArray[n] is undefined ///then why can I see its value in the scripts->watch tab?
addCharge(n=100)js_operation.php (line 73)
fireNeuron(n=73)js_operation.php (line 66)
stepNetwork()
```

The thing that gets me is that when I pass a number it works, and when I evaluate `neuronArray`, `neuronArray[n]`, `neuronArray[n]`. `charge` etc in the scripts pane (watch area), it always is able to reference it.

Comment: the fact that you have `neuronArray.charge` and `neuronArray[n].charge` might show problems.

Comment: good catch, fixed, same issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is the problem:

```
sendChargeTo = neuronArray[n].outputs[p];
addCharge(sendChargeTo);
```

You're not sending `addCharge` an index, you're sending it `neuronArray[n].outputs[p]`.

Comment: typeof(sendChargeTo);//returns "number"

Comment: actually...var sendChargeTo = neuronArray[n].outputs; sendChargeTo[p]++; worked... so you were right. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Raynos's comments about the last two lines in `fireNeuron` I can't see an obvious problem.

Perhaps you have a globals problem? I think that variables `i`, `p`, and `sendChargeTo` should be declared local with `var`.